# jQuery .off without selector is not working

Tags: jquery

I have some code that wires up event handlers to a bootstrap modal. This code is getting called twice so it calls `.off()` before calling `.on()` to make sure the event handlers don't execute twice:

```
$("#learnMoreModal")
        .off("show.bs.modal", learnMoreModalShow)
        .on("show.bs.modal", learnMoreModalShow)
        .off("hidden.bs.modal", learnMoreModalHidden)
        .on("hidden.bs.modal", learnMoreModalHidden);
```

But `learnMoreModalShow` and `learnMoreModalHidden` are executing twice. Why isn't my call to `.off()` removing it?

Comment: It's not clear from your minimal code sample, but perhaps you could use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead?

Comment: I don't *think* the OP is saying he only wants it to fire only once, ever. He wants to make sure that only one event handler is hooked up. E.g., he's saying he's calling a method "HookUpMyEventHandlers" possible X number of times, but he wants to make sure that the event handlers are only hooked up once. (I think is what he's saying).

Comment: @aquinas If you read the docs for .one(), you are getting single instances of the handler, but you create a new single instance every time .one() is run, if that makes sense.

Comment: @aquinas you are correct. Blazmonger, that's a little too much of a bandaid for me here but I appreciate you pointing it out. It was a stupid problem, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I was afraid of, it was something dumb. Though the function that wires up my events can be called twice in certain circumstances, it actually wasn't in this case. I stepped into the jQuery source and found jQuery was assigning an ID of 94 to `learnMoreModalShow` during the first call to `.on()` and then in the next call to `.off()` its ID was undefined. That led me to find that someone had added a second reference to my entire .js file so the whole thing was running twice...not just the function that wires up the events.

So the answer is: `.off()` is working properly as it is written above. If the handler is executing anyway, you might either have multiple instances of the handler function in use, or some other code adding the handler elsewhere after `.off` completes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at using the

> .unbind()

functionality in jquery.  I use it when I need to redefine click events so they do not execute multiple functions.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I'm using jQuery 1.11 so `off()` would be the preferred way according to the doc.